# Overline Text in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, text-styling, text-widget

I can apply an `underline` or `overstrike` style to text in `Text` widget.

Is it possible to do an overline?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack(padx=4,pady=4,fill=tk.BOTH,expand=tk.YES)

text.tag_configure('underline', underline=True)
text.tag_configure('overstrike', overstrike=True)

text.insert(tk.END, 'Underline text.\n','underline')
text.insert(tk.END, 'Overstrike text.\n','overstrike')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well, from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_fonts.htm, it seems that only options are: `family, size, weight, slant, underline, overstrike`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do an overline.